# Projection and Positive matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Sorry my question was not clearly stated. I will ask it more clearly.

Let $G$ be a matrix with only nonnegative elements with linearly independent
columns. Then there exists a column, ${\bf g}$ of $G$ such that the orthogonal projection of ${\bf g}$
on the remaining columns of G is a nonnegative linear combination of those columns.
In other words, for a suitable column ${\bf g}$ of $G$ the vector ${\bf x}$ that minimizes 
$\parallel G^* {\bf x} - {\bf g}\parallel$ has nonnegative elements, where $G^*$
is a matrix consisting of all the columns of $G$ except ${\bf g}$.

Is the above a correct statement?

Comment: What do you mean by "projection"?
If you mean orthogonal projection, then the unit matrix is a counterexample, but the only one.

Comment: Voting to close as a duplicate of http://mathoverflow.net/questions/117278/projection-and-positive-matrices

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "positive linear combination"?

Try G=I.  If you select any column of G, you'll find that its projection onto the space spanned by the other columns of G is the 0 vector.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried to clarify the question but I think my question got closed. Since I am new here, I am not sure what to do about that. However, to respond to your question, I meant actually a linear combination with nonnegative coefficients. So basically you have a matrix with positive elements and you want to show the existence of a column, which when orthogonally projected on the remaining columns, can be represented as a nonnegative linear combination of those columns.





Comment: Sorry about this, I always mean nonnegative when I say positive. 